# Solve for x : If $( 1 + \tan x ) ( 1 - \tan x ) ( \sec^ 2 x ) + 2 ^ { \tan^ 2 x } = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $( 1 + \tan x ) ( 1 - \tan x ) ( \sec^ 2 x )  + 2 ^ {  \tan^ 2 x  } = 
> 0$ , then find the number of solutions in the interval $( -\pi/2 , \pi/2 )$.

I did solve , but I get 2 solutions instead of 4 as stated in answer.

---

My solution :

$$( 1 + \tan x ) ( 1 - \tan x ) ( \sec^2 x ) + 2 ^ {  \tan^ 2 x  } = 0 \\
( 1 - \tan^2 x ) ( 1 + \tan^2 x ) + 2 ^ {  \tan^ 2 x  } = 0 \\
1 - \tan^4 x + 2 ^ {  \tan^ 2 x  } = 0$$

Let $\tan^2 x = z$

$\implies 2 ^ z = z^2 - 1$

By hit and trial ( putting random integers )

I got $z = 3$

so then $x = n\pi \pm \pi/3$.

In $( -\pi/2 , \pi/2 )$ , I got , $-\pi/3$, $\pi/3$ only i.e. 2 solutions .

But the answer in the book says , there are 4 .

Comment: There is another solution for $z<0$ that is not an integer.

Comment: @David Whats that value of z then ?

Comment: draw the graphs of $z^2 $ and $2^z+1$ you will have two solutions one positive $z$ and one negative $z$

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma No, one negative, two positive.

Comment: ya you are right its two positive

Comment: I think you have to find the non-integer roots numerically.

Comment: @David How do I solve x^2 -1 = 2^x without a graphing calculator ? How do I solve it arithmetically ?

Comment: @Ricky You can solve it numerically, e.g. using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: @user236182 We havent been taught about newton method . Its a high school math , isnt there any other way ?

Comment: I don't know of any arithmetic way.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739145/how-to-solve-1-tan2x-sec2x2-tan2x-0?rq=1